# Spring @configure annotation usage without bean definitions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, annotations

I have some experience with spring dependency injection and transaction management but I am new to spring security. When i was reading an [article](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/) related to spring security, I found that `@Configuration` annotation is used in an example but there were no bean definitions to be found.

According to my understanding, `@Configuration` annotation is used in classes which contain bean definitions. I need to know that what does the `@Configuration` annotation do in this example.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;

   ... // web stuff here

  @Override
  public configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) {
    builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).withUser("dave")
      .password("secret").roles("USER");
  }

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not mandatory to have `Bean` definitions in Spring managed classes.

In this case `@Configuration` (which wraps `@Component`) is used to indicate to Spring that this class should be instantiated and all it's dependencies should be injected - in this case that's `DataSource` and `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. This is an example of Inversion of Control principle.

Spring also provides these ConfigurerAdapter hook points, where you can tweak the default configuration of an already instantiated component.
This is exactly what is happening in your Configuration class.

Comment: So this essentially tells spring that instantiate a object of `ApplicationSecurity ` , so that when we use that kind of behaviour this overridden version is invoked. Is that correct ?

Comment: Not exactly - when you extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (as in the above case) you are customizing an already created instance of WebSecurityConfigurer object. The instance is being past in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and you can modify the default configuration etc. Look up the Adapter pattern if necessary.